# Reversing a math formula

Tags: javascript, math, algebra

I found this formula to calculate mortgage payments

The interest rate is **IntRate**, **Pa** represents the payment, **PrValue** is the present value of the loan, and **Period** is the number of years the money is borrowed.

```
Pa = (PrValue * IntRate) / (1 - Math.pow (1 + IntRate, - (Period * PPay)))
```

What I would like to do is get the value of **isPrValue**

```
isPrValue = ?
```

[source](http://www.1stop-mortgagecalculator.com/mortgage-calculator-code.htm#Canadian-Mortgage-Formula)

Comment: You obviously already know how to convert math to javascript equivalents, so why the question?

Comment: Um, do the reverse?  If you have `IntRate`, `Period`, `PPay`, and `Pa` values, it's not hard to do it backward.  Grade school algebra.

Comment: im not all that good with math so i been playing around with [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x++4.2%29%2F%281-%281%2B4.2%29%5E-30%29+%3D+252000)

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Even math.stackexchange.com will expect someone to know how to do high school algebra.  Would you send someone there to do simple arithmetic problems?  Multiplication tables?  Where does it end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken algebra?

```
PrValue = (Pa * (1-Math.pow(1+IntRate, - (Period*PPay))))/IntRate
```

Comment: yes but im not very good at it .. thanks for the help